# android not running on my phone, but on my emulator does

Tags: android

i wrote this ftp upload method...it works great on the emulator but doesnt on my phone...

can someone tell me why not?

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
                FileInputStream fis = null;

                try {
                    client.connect("ftp.atw.hu");
                    client.login("festivale", "festivale12");
                    Log.d("TravellerLog :: ", "Csatlakozva: ftp.atw.hu");

                    //
                    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
                    //
                    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    String substr = globalconstant.path.substring(4, globalconstant.path.length());
                    String filename = substr + "/Festivale.db";
                    Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", substr + "/Festivale.db");
                    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

                    //
                    // Store file to server
                    //
                    client.storeFile("Festivale.db", fis);
                    Log.d("TravellerLog :: ", "Feltöltve");
                    client.logout();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fis != null) {
                            fis.close();
                        }
                        client.disconnect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

pls help i'm trying to do this ftp almost 3hours ago :S

Comment: What excatly means "does not work"? Can you describe a bit more detailed whats happening? In case of an error you should also provide the strack trace.

Comment: oops...i got force close

Comment: provide the error from logcat

Comment: thats what i cant...my phone if got fc its freezing than rebooting...

Comment: without the error stack it's hard to tell where's the problem

Comment: is there a program which saves automaticly the logcat?

Comment: normally the log stays in the logcat view even if you unplug your device..I'm assuming you're using eclipse

Comment: but i havent got a logcat in eclipse because i'm running the apk on my phone

Comment: so what.. as long as your device is plugged you can view your phone's log.. to make sure you see the phone's log go DDMS view and select your device from device list.this way you'll see the device's log

Comment: should i turn on the usb debugging?

Comment: of course usb debugging mode should be on

Comment: doesnt get any log :S any idea what could it be?

Comment: Make sure in your ddms your device is selected.

Comment: Can anyone try this code on a phone cause I can't have log

Answer (score 0):

On devices, you need to use a separate thread to handle the ftp connection.

"By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities."[android.developer.com/guide/components/services.html]